# BigQuery export selected field from Firebase firestore history data to excel

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

I am writing big query code to export firestore history data to excel. I want to get all the data of a particular machineId which is present in my firestore. this is the structure of my firestore

[image]

and this is the code:- https://codesandbox.io/s/young-rain-6s0hzj

Error:- `Unrecognized name: data`

but this is giving some error can anyone suggest me some documentation.

Comment: Hi @MOHAMMAD ZEESHAN, You can try loading the data from BigQuery by following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore) and then from BigQuery you can export it to excel sheet as mentioned in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data) . Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @ShipraSarkar I don't need all data of my Firestore . I have All_Machine node under All_ machine I have many machine id like f4e7a8e350cc ,  A825a8e350cc. and under machine id I have data and i want to access data of a Particular machine Id or single machine id at a time for example if I want to access data of  f4e7a8e350cc this machine id first in a excel sheet and then another machine id in another excel sheet.

Comment: Hi @MOHAMMAD ZEESHAN, For your requirement, you can try filtering the data using queries as mentioned in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering). Let me know if that helps.